# Replace and sort perl array elements

Tags: perl, sorting

I'm looking for an elegant solution to sort an array and then replace the numerical values with letters.  I got something working here but it is a huge if/else monster that, I'm sure, can be written much shorter.

Sample code:

```
my $values = "70,20,50";
my @singlevalues = sort(split(/,/,$values));
ifmonster();
my $result = "RBG";
```

`$values` has three color values in it, where the first one represents "R", the second one "G" and the last one "B".  I want to sort these values and in the end get a string like `$result` which is sorted form biggest to smallest represent by the letters.

So "70,20,50" results in "RBG" while "20,50,30" results in "GBR".

Thank you

Comment: Both 70 and 30 map to R?

Comment: @davorg In the second example R is 20, G is 50, and B is 30, so, sorted values gives you 50 (G), 30 (B), and 20 (R), hence `"GBR"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hashless solution:

```
my @color = split /,/, $value, 3;
my @order = sort { $color[$b] <=> $color[$a] } 0..2;
my $result = join "", qw(R G B)[@order];
```

The `@order` list stores a permutation which is later applied to the letter list.

Comment: As the old saying goes, TIMTOWTDI!

Comment: I particularly like this Way To Do It; it's short but also easy-to-read and self descriptive.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a hash would store the data in the way you want to access it.  Building it is fairly simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $values = "70,20,50";
my %components_by_name;
@components_by_name{qw/R G B/} = split ",", $values;
my $result = join "",
    sort { $components_by_name{$b} <=> $components_by_name{$a} }
    keys %components_by_name;

print "$result\n";
```

You can declare an empty hash by saying:

```
my %hash;
```

When assigning to a hash you can say

```
$hash{key} = "value";
```

But if assigning a bunch of values whose keys you know in advance, it is often easier to use a hash slice:

```
@hash{"key 1", "key 2", "key 3"} = ("value 1", "value 2", "value 3");
```

If your keys don't contain whitespace, you can use the `qw//` operator to reduce the amount of noise on the line

```
@hash{qw/key1 key2 key3/} = ("value 1", "value 2", "value 3");
```

Accessing a value in a hash is similar to how you access values in an array, but you use `{}` instead of `[]` and the key is a string instead of a number:

```
my $value = $hash{key1}; #$value now holds "value 1";
```

To get all of the keys in a hash, you can use the [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) function:

```
my @keys = keys %hash;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for your specific example.  I will leave it to you to generalize. :)

```
my $values = "70,20,50";
my @values = split(/,/,$values);
my $hash = {$values[0] => "R", $values[1] => "G", $values[2] => "B"};
print(join("", (map {$hash->{$_}} (sort { $b <=> $a } @values))));
print "\n";
```

(Edited to fix the problem found by Chas Owens in the comments below.)

Comment: `reverse sort @values` sorts lexically (i.e. alphabetically).  You want `sort { $b <=> $a } @values`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
my $values = "70,20,50";
my @singlevalues = split(/,/,$values);
my %colourMap = ();

$colourMap{$singlevalues[0]} = 'R';
$colourMap{$singlevalues[1]} = 'G';
$colourMap{$singlevalues[2]} = 'B';

foreach $key(sort {$b <=> $a} keys %colourMap)
{
    $result = $result . $colourMap{$key};
}

print $result;
```

Comment: Assigning an empty list to a hash you just created is a [noop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP).  Also, a [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) is a bit more sensible than a `for` loop that concatenates.  You should also be using the [`strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) pragmas.

Comment: I think the OP just wanted to see the logic, so I didn't use strict and warnings.

Comment: Then why include the `#!` line?  It makes it look like a complete program, and it isn't a complete (Modern) Perl program with the `strict` pragma.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plot of yet another method (though it's probably the C way): reduce the *ifmonster* to a set of logical operations and pick the right answer from a predefined array.

```
# defined once
our @rgbindex = qw(RGB GRB null GBR RBG null BRG BGR); 

# later, e.g. in a sub
my ($r, $g, $b) = split /,/, $values;
my $i = (($r < $g) ? 1 : 0)
      + (($r < $b) ? 2 : 0)
      + (($g < $b) ? 4 : 0);
return $rgbindex[$i];
```

The `null`s in @rgbindex appear because they correspond to illegal setups. (And also 2^3 (number of bit combos) = 8, but 3! (the number of permutations) is only 6)

Comment: Are you trying to use `our` like `state` (i.e. to only have to initialize it once?)?

Comment: I'm using `our` to point out it's a constant; looks like it wasn't clear. Of course, it won't prevent re-initialisation. With newer Perls using `state` is the right way.

Comment: And if it is constant, then use the [`Readonly`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Readonly/Readonly.pm) module or [`constant`](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html): `use constant RGBINDEX => qw/RGB GRB null GBR RBG null BRG BGR/;` and then `return (RGBINDEX)[ ($r < $g) + 2*($r < $b) + 4*($g < $b) ];`

Comment: @Chas.-Owens: Yes, your variant is better. It's also the shortest in this topic! (And I suppose the fastest).

Comment: I doubt it is the fastest.  I think the conditional operator is probably faster than the multiplication operator.  Of course, it would be trivial to write a benchmark.

Comment: A quick [benchmark](http://codepad.org/4NkQSQ4x) shows that the conditional method using an array is the fastest followed closely by the multiplication method using an array.  The next tier is the array method, if using the constant list, and multiplication using the constant list with the hash key method following closely.  The slowest method uses the hash values for the RGB characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
my %hash;
my $values = "70,20,50";

@hash{split(/,/,$values)} = qw/R G B/;
print @hash{sort keys %hash};
```

Comment: `sort keys %hash` sorts lexically (i.e. `"5"` is a higher value than `"10"`). You want `sort { $a <=> $b } keys %hash`, and you probably really want `sort { $b <=> $a } keys %hash` because the OP specified "sorted form biggest to smallest".